# Quiero tomar el parámetro `id` en una ruta pero quiero mostrar en el url otro parámetro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quería saber si esto se puede realizar sabiendo lo siguiente:

> el parámetro que quiero mostrar en vez del `id` es el nombre y en la base de datos no es un parámetro único
>
> desearía poder tomar el parámetro `id` para luego poder mostrar el otro parámetro que no es único en la base de datos (nombre)

¿Esto se puede realizar?, dejaré la ruta que utilizo para este caso:

```
get 'user/:id' => 'users#userProfile', as: 'user_profile'
```

de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí que se puede, tu mejor opción es usar la gema "[Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)", que internamente se encargará de generar el mapeo necesario entre las ids reales y las que se muestran en tu url. Este tipo de ID es el que se usa en muchos blogs e incluso en algunas páginas de noticias.